# cannot seem to update the rails executable in bin/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have a rails project where I use `bin/rails` instead of just calling `rails` its self. upon upgrading to rails 4.2, I did:

```
rm -rf .bundle/gems
bundle
```

When everything finished, I did `bin/rails`

```
$ bin/rails
Looks like your app's ./bin/rails is a stub that was generated by Bundler.

In Rails 4, your app's bin/ directory contains executables that are versioned
like any other source code, rather than stubs that are generated on demand.

Here's how to upgrade:

  bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
  rake rails:update:bin         # Use the new Rails 4 executables
  git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control

You may need to remove bin/ from your .gitignore as well.

When you install a gem whose executable you want to use in your app,
generate it and add it to source control:

  bundle binstubs some-gem-name
  git add bin/new-executable

/Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/Libraries-and-Helpers/Xaaron/.bundle/gems/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:44:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/Libraries-and-Helpers/Xaaron/config/boot (LoadError)
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/Libraries-and-Helpers/Xaaron/.bundle/gems/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:44:in `block in exec_app_rails'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/Libraries-and-Helpers/Xaaron/.bundle/gems/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:34:in `loop'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/Libraries-and-Helpers/Xaaron/.bundle/gems/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:34:in `exec_app_rails'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/Libraries-and-Helpers/Xaaron/.bundle/gems/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/Libraries-and-Helpers/Xaaron/.bundle/gems/gems/railties-4.2.0/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/Adam/Documents/Rails-Projects/Libraries-and-Helpers/Xaaron/.bundle/gems/gems/railties-4.2.0/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:16:in `load'
    from bin/rails:16:in `<main>'
```

So I assumed I could do, after doing `bundle config --delete bin`:

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

But then I am given:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'rails'
```

I am running this from the root of a rails engine that I have created. I am curious as to whats going on. Should I run this command from the dummy app? I suspect not as the `bin/` directory is at the root of the engine directory and not the dummy app.

Comment: The `rake rails:update:bin` command should be run from the main rails application where the rails engine is mounted, not from the root of the rails engine. Tip: If you run `rake -T rails` from any folder where `rake` is visible, it will show all the rails tasks available.

Comment: acceptthe first part of my question happens in the engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer based off the comment to the question is to run:

```
rake app:rails:update:bin
```

at the root of the engine.